# In Facebook API is Next/Prev pagination pointers in the opposite direction?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, pagination, facebook-fql, facebook-php-sdk

I'm trying to perform a simple pagination based on time through a facebook endpoint. I was getting results that didn't match my `since`.

An example call `<username>/statuses?since=1390176000`
returns this pagination:

```
    "paging": {
    "previous": "https://graph.facebook.com/8489236245/statuses?since=1390500000&limit=25&__paging_token=<num>", 
    "next": "https://graph.facebook.com/8489236245/statuses?limit=25&until=1390250670&__paging_token=<num>"
  }
```

My expected behavior was that after a query with `since` I will iterate on `next` till I reach `NOW`. But when doing the query they provide with `until=1390250670` I actually get OLDER results. Is there any logical explanation for this? Should I just use the previous paging ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are looking at the user's statuses, the pagination is reversed as the data is ordered in reverse chronological order. The newest entries are always on the first page, so paginating to the `next` page will always give you older entries.

Unfortunately, the Facebook documentation doesn't mention the ordering for this API call.